# Firebug Net Panel Logs

Tags: firebug, firefox3.5

Is there a way to have firebug retain the activities log even after navigating to another page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: Just thought I'd edit this since all the answers on this page are now out of date... As of version 1.5, Firebug lets you retain your net panel activities between page loads by selecting the `Persist` option (at the top left, next to `Clear`).

<del>Not that I'm aware of out of the box... If you're just trying to record the header request/response info (as opposed to the actual content & timings), you could try [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829). Not as pretty, but I still find it useful in certain debugging scenarios.</del>

Comment: Just a note that 'Persist' does not work across domains or subdomains (meaning  a redirect from  auth.mysite.com to www.mysite.com will not persist)...at least as of Firebug 1.9.1.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Firebug extension called [Firebug Net Panel History Overlay](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7189). That probably does what you want.

If you want something more than that, you might want to have a look at packet sniffers like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/).

Comment: Just had a look at that "Firebug Net Panel History Overlay" extension, since I hadn't heard of it... unfortunately it looks like it hasn't been updated in over a year & doesn't work with the current versions of Firebug... unless you know where's there's a newer version?

Comment: I only just found out about it myself (here: http://getfirebug.com/extensions) when I was trying to find if Steve Souders had written any more info about the various packet sniffers... I didn't realise it was a year old, but I tried it and it works just fine for me on both Firefox 3.0 and Firefox 3.5 (w/ Firebug 1.4.1).

Comment: Does work with Firebug 1.4.2 on FF 3.5.2, I was trying to use it to track data transferred by a frame that reloads itself. It didn't work for my purposes, but it did track successive page loads in firefox. HttpWatch did what I wanted, though the output isn't as nice as firebug.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647). This does exactly what you want, and also what I wanted. That's why I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post that explains how to persist Net panel entries across page reloads.
http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-observe-page-redirects/

Honza